# C# MultipartFormDataContent() equivalent for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In C# there is the MultipartFormDataContent() class, and I need to find some equivalent for Flutter.

EDIT: Being more specific with my question, I have this C# code that returns a MultipartFormDataContent(), but I have no idea how to rewrite it in dart (mainly because of the mentioned class).

[image]

Comment: Looks just like a `MultipartRequest` https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this package 

https://pub.dev/packages/dio

var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'wendux',
  'age': 25,
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
  'files': [
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text1.txt', filename: 'text1.txt'),
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text2.txt', filename: 'text2.txt'),
  ]
});
var response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

Comment: I just edited my problem with a more specific description. I don't know if the example you sent can be applied to this case.